# Confusing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'n' of undefined only happens when JSON result has a single item, why?

Tags: javascript, json, undefined, typeerror

I am fetching json data from an RSS feed through `YQL`. When there are multiple items in the results array everything works as expected.

When there is only a single item in the results array, however, I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined

This is the relevant bit of code where the variable is being defined from the json result. The 'content' property referenced in the error is from the $isbn variable where I'm grabbing the `guid.content` for each item in the results:

```
if (data.query.count > 0) {  
  $.each(data.query.results.item, function(i, book) {
    var $title = book.title;
    var $url = book.link;
    var $description = book.description;
    var $isbn = book.guid.content.split(' ', 1);
```

Here is the json data that is being returned for the rss feed that has only one result [JSON Data](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20rss%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwebpac.sutherlandshire.nsw.gov.au%2Ffeeds%2Fnewjuniordvds.xml%27&format=json) :

```
{
  query: {
    count: 1,
    created: "2015-10-01T08:31:51Z",
    lang: "en-US",
    results: {
      item: {
        title: "Hi-5. Sharing stories [videorecording] : Spin me round.",
        link: "http://webpac.sutherlandshire.nsw.gov.au/record=b1252345*eng",
        description: "The big story book is open and Hi-5 are sharing all their story fun with you!",
        guid: {
          isPermaLink: "false",
          content: "9398711204390"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However the same code runs perfectly well when I request the json data from an rss feed with multiple items. There are no errors and the $isbn variable  is defined and used.

I have set up a codepen that shows this behaviour at [Test Case for AJAX fail](http://codepen.io/boycetrus/pen/QjddmV)

I have understood what the error is referring to but I don't understand why  it is only produced when there is a single item in the json data.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that when returning multiple items data.query.results.item is treated as a Array, but when only returning one it is treated as a Object.

This means that $.each is reading through all the attributes of the single item.

One way of fixing this would be to treat single results differently.

```
if (data.query.count > 0) {  
  $.each(data.query.results.item, function(i, book) {
  var $title = book.title;
  var $url = book.link;
  var $description = book.description;
  var $isbn = book.guid.content.split(' ', 1);
  )};
}else if(data.query.count===1){
  var $title = data.query.results.item.title;
  var $url = data.query.results.item.link;
  var $description = data.query.results.item.description;
  var $isbn = data.query.results.item.guid.content.split(' ', 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Magnus. This did the trick.  I missed the array notation difference in two jason results. I had to reorganise my code but I have it working now at [link](http://codepen.io/boycetrus/pen/gambeB?editors=001)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to debug it?
http://prntscr.com/8mh030

I think you miss the debth of output and need to change
`$.each(data.query.results.item, function(i, book)`
to
`$.each(data.query.results, function(i, book)`